# How To Implement Auto Scroll to TextView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview, infinite-scroll

I want to implement a program that lets the user click on a button and the textView should auto scroll to the bottom. I have tried many things available on the internet but not working as I want, I am new to Xcode, Please help...

This is what I have tried:

```
self.textView.isScrollEnabled = false
UIView.animate(withDuration: 12.0, delay: 0,options: ([UIView.AnimationOptions .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
    self.textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.textView.bounds.size.height)
}, completion:  { _ in })
```

This is working but not as I want. It only scrolls the text which is on the screen not all the text.. please help..

I have also tried this:

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
CGPoint point = textfield.frame.origin ;
scrollView.contentOffset = point
```

I got this from the internet but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `bounds.size.height` and `frame.size.height` here is just the size of your `TextView` in your parent view.

The thing you should notice here is the content inside your `textView` which is your `contentSize`. You just need to scroll to the end of your `contentSize.height`

Code will be like this

```swift
// scroll to the end of your content size height
self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.textView.contentSize.height), animated: true)
```